# error in sjPlot sjp.xtab command used to get "cleanest" graphic?

Tags: r, plot, statistics, sjplot

I am trying to generate a bar plot with this data:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjstats)
data("efc")
```

i use the following to generate the default xtab plot from the sjPlot.

```
sjp.xtab(x = efc$e42dep,
         grp = efc$c82cop1)
```

But i prefer show only a "cleanest" plot, without information (i prefer to link to a table if you want the specific data), so i try this:

```
sjp.xtab(x = efc$e42dep,
         grp = efc$c82cop1,show.total = F, show.n = F,show.prc = F)
```

but i get this

> Error in sjp.xtab(x = efc$e42dep, grp = efc$c82cop1, show.total = F,
>   show.n = F,  :    objeto 'ggvaluelabels' no encontrado

i use R in a Spanish language OS, so...

is basically

> object 'ggvaluelabels' not found

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `show.values = FALSE` to prevent annotating the graph.

```
sjp.xtab(x = efc$e42dep, grp = efc$c82cop1)
```

[image]

```
# show.values = FALSE
sjp.xtab(x = efc$e42dep, grp = efc$c82cop1, show.values = FALSE )
```

[image]

```
sjp.xtab(x = efc$e42dep, grp = efc$c82cop1,show.total = F, show.n = F,show.prc = F, show.values = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That is the way i want my plot.  I prefer this. Can you tell me what is wrong with my code? I want to learn more about this packague. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, i get it. i never found a command where two parameters works in this way before. I suppose that the error message don't help me too much. i am a bit new in r code. Thanks, your edited post help me a lot.